# Facebook canvas app vs Facebook mobile web app

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-canvas

I'm a bit confused about the difference between a facebook canvas application and a facebook mobile web application.  Here is the context of my confusion..

I have a canvas application, let us call its namespace as myfbapp, and I basically can access it from https://apps.facebook.com/myfbapp and after I login to FB it opens up with in Facebook. I'm using java (apache / tomcat) for my server side implementation and for simplicity sake let us say I just have an index.html and a authenticationfilter.java (which implements Filter) in my web application.  I don't have any Facebook specific Javascript API (no FB.init() javascript or anything like that ) or code in my index.html. Whenever user accesses my canvas application I first get a request to my web application where I get the signed_request , oauth_token , FB user ID etc which I can use for my internal authentication, session creation etc.  I have absolutely no issues with this canvas application and every thing works fine.  Please note that when user accesses this app the request I get from the browser to my app server has the signed_request , user_id etc.

Now I wanted to make this app available on mobile devices as well and I thought, oh well all I need to do is add the mobile URL for this app in the mobile web app section in Facebook for the same myfbapp.  I did that and as expected when I login to facebook from my android phone myfbapp is listed under the apps section, so far so good.  The problem starts when I click on the app.  I get the request on my app server but it doesn't contain the signed_request , user_id etc.. ????? I was expecting the mobile app to work the same way as the canvas app but apparently it doesn't or I'm doing some thing wrong.

Then I started reading more about facebook mobile app at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/#register where it talks about adding various Facebook Javascript API's in the index.html (I never did anything like that in my canvas app) and then I started thinking , may be then mobile web app is more (or exactly) like a regular web app  with FB connect and not like canvas application (meaning it doesn't really load with in Facebook) , is this true?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On mobile facebook you can not see any custom pages/tabs. They are apparently wokring on that at the moment.

So it will be different to a canvas app. Your mobile app will be a completely seperate site and page not in an iFrame on Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Some behaviour i discovered recently with Facebook Canvas / Page Tabs on mobile devices.
Maybe this helps to understand a little bit better how facebook behaves in mobile context.

---

### Mobile Browser

**Access App URL**

*Example URL* `http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/`

Redirects to the configured mobile website under `Settings > Website > Mobile Site URL` and adds additional params `/?ref=web_canvas&code=<signed_request_code_field>`

About the signed_request code field

> An OAuth Code which can be exchanged for a valid user access token via a subsequent server-side request

**Access App Center**

There is no way to access the Facebook App Center via the mobile browser.

**Access Page Tab**

*Example URL* `http://facebook.com/a_facebook_page/custom_page_tab_url`

Custom Page Tabs are not visible via the mobile browser.

**Facebook Open Graph Search**

Searching for *myapp* returns the link to the Facebook Canvas.

Same behaviour like *Access App URL via Mobile Browser*

---

### Mobile Facebook Client

**Access App URL**

There is no way to access this url directly.

**Access App Center**

There is no way to access the Facebook App Center.

**Access Page Tab**

*Example URL* `http://facebook.com/a_facebook_page/custom_page_tab_url`

Custom Page Tabs are not visible via the mobile facebook client.

**Facebook Open Graph Search**

It says that this app is not compatible with this devices.

You need to register an iOS / Android App and send the user to this app to get rid of this error. Probably it helps the user if you add the link to the *standalone* application to the  Facebook description of the app. Which should then be visible there.