# Why Facebook request on mobile web app is not working?

Tags: facebook

I have read the other threads about how the FB requests are only for Canvas apps, but maybe these answer are a bit old and I want to be sure this is current information, because on this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/ FB says:

If you have built a Canvas or **Mobile Web application**, Requests are a great way to enable users to invite their friends.

Difference between Canvas & mobile: [Facebook canvas app vs Facebook mobile web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753179/facebook-canvas-app-vs-facebook-mobile-web-app)

Then, are requests just for Canvas even if they say that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

You need a canvas url in the app settings to have access to requests. These requests can be done on your mobile web app (not just the the canvas).

If you just want a mobile app and not a canvas app but still use request, fill the canvas url on the app panel and on the pageof this url use a javascript redirection to your mobile app.

Comment: Also, it's important to fill in the mobile web app settings: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/web/build/#register