# Mobile Web URL and the signed_request

Tags: facebook, mobile

I've set up my FB app so that it has a Mobile Web URL component. I've noted from testing that whenever I navigate to canvas URL of my app on a mobile device, Facebook automatically redirects the mobile to the defined Mobile Web URL.

If I do the same from desktop, the canvas URL is loaded in to the browser. In other words, if FB detects a mobile device when navigating to an app's canvas URL, it will immediately redirect to a defined Mobile Web URL and not load the canvas URL content.

The problem with this is that when the canvas URL loads, FB passes to it a signed_request form parameter. Yet, when it redirects to the Mobile Web URL it does not.

I noticed when checking a network sniffer that when on mobile Facebook redirects the app.facebook.com URL to m.facebook.com, and thought perhaps the signed_request was getting lost along the way. But when checking the first call to the canvas URL there was no signed_request there either.

It's like Facebook only provides the signed_request when it processes the canvas URL, which in the case of mobile is never.

Has anyone any insight or advice on how to get the signed_request? My only thought at the moment is forcing the user to authorise the app on mobile as soon as they are redirected, but i'd rather not do that if possible (I'm not a fan of gating techniques)

Cheers

Lee

--- EDIT ---

Closing - see my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753179/facebook-canvas-app-vs-facebook-mobile-web-app

Comment: Thanks dude, saw that after I made my post. Have since came to the same conclusion and have coded mobile-specific auth flow. Sucks a bit but hey-ho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since come to the conclusion that Mobile URLs do not receive the signed_request, and to get the same sort of data requires the users to be put through the FB Auth process. Closing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your mobile app should be passed a "code" in the query string if the person has authorized your app. Your backend can exchange that code for an access_token and then you can use that to get the current user info by requesting https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=[token retrieved from code exchange]. That will allow you to automatically login the current user.

But yes, you do not receive info like the current user's country, locale, and age if they have not authenticated. That is a limitation of mobile web apps currently.