# Facebook Signed_request invalid via mobile app

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api, mobile

We have an fb canvas made from .net mvc that works well via desktop but it doesn't work well in mobile app. We send request then if someone on fb mobile tap on request and opens up the web app, the signed_request returned is different than the desktop counterpart. The payload is missing and it seems shorter than the desktop's. I'm trying to read it as "code" and try getting auth token via https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxx&code=[code]&redirect_uri=???. The problem with this is I don't know what the redirect_uri supplied or maybe it's not a code.

Can you guys help me with this or there's no other way but once they click request via mobile app we have them relogin in our web app to grab their fbuserid? And if there's another approach in handling mobile app requests.

[Mobile Web URL and the signed_request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283350/mobile-web-url-and-the-signed-request)

This is already outdated so maybe there's a solution already.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. What you can do is add an extra authorization in your login flow when then access your canvas url via facebook mobile app. You send them to

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=

passing the redirect uri and scope then grab the new generated "code" param and grab the aut token via graph api. Then you can access their facebook detail as you would normally. I've read answers like there's no signed request in mobile web and approach it differently without stating what that approach is. Hope someone can be helped by this answer.

Thanks